# My touchpad isn't working

Tags: release-loki, settings, touchpad

I recently installed Elementary OS in my laptop. (Toshiba Satellite C55-B5356) and I cannot seem to get my touchpad to work. As far as I can tell, it's enabled. xinput list seems to recognize it

```
SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad  id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

and it shows as enabled in its properties

```
Device 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad':
Device Enabled (140):   1
```

Even /var/log/Xorg.0.log makes me think it is being recognized it, yet it doesn't work.

```
config/udev: Adding input device SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad (/dev/input/event5)
SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Applying InputClass "evdev touchpad catchall"
SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Applying InputClass "evdev touchscreen catchall"
SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Applying InputClass "touchpad catchall"
 SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Applying InputClass "Default clickpad buttons"
SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Applying InputClass "touchpad catchall"
 SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Applying InputClass "Default clickpad buttons"
 LoadModule: "synaptics"
 Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/synaptics_drv.so
Module synaptics: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
compiled for 1.18.1, module version = 1.8.2
Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 22.1
Using input driver 'synaptics' for 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad'
SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: always reports core events
Option "Device" "/dev/input/event5"
synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: ignoring touch events for semi-    multitouch device
synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: x-axis range 1192 - 5752 (res 51)
synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: y-axis range 1002 - 4872 (res 77)
synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: pressure range 0 - 255
synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: finger width range 0 - 15
synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: buttons: left right double triple
synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Vendor 0x2 Product 0x7
synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: touchpad found
SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: always reports core events
Option "config_info"         "udev:/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input5/event5"
XINPUT: Adding extended input device "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" (type: TOUCHPAD, id 11)
synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) MinSpeed is now constant deceleration 2.5
synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) MaxSpeed is now 1.75
synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) AccelFactor is now 0.033
SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) acceleration profile 1
SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: touchpad found
config/udev: Adding input device SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad     (/dev/input/mouse0)
SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Ignoring device from InputClass "touchpad     ignore duplicates"
config/udev: Adding input device Toshiba input device (/dev/input/event6)
```

Does anyone have any idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that Synaptics drivers for linux are no longer being mantained, so is espected that some people wil have bugs, Archlinux community recommends to use the `libinput` package instead of synaptics. With you output seems like the kernel doesn't know what driver use, maybe is missing some configuration?

First able do you cheked out if you disabled the touchpad input? Fn + F5 keys
If the problem persists update the post with your synaptics configuration in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/somethingwith-synaptics.conf`.

Check out this [post](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=174662) seems that someone fixed that with the command

`xinput set-prop <11> "Device Enabled" #`

Also you can check the ArchLinux Wiki for further information [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Touchpad_Synaptics). I hope this helps.

Comment: I figured out what happened after a while. I did try that command but it wouldn't work for me. Apparently, I disabled the touchpad in Windows before installing elementary OS, so it had a hardware block. Had to get a live usb windows and unlock from there. Thank you for your help though!