# my elantech touchpad doesn't work

Tags: release-juno, touchpad, drivers

I'm new to Linux and I did fresh install of elementary OS 5.0. Everything is working fine but the touchpad doesn't work and I don't have any idea on how to troubleshoot.

It looks like its detected

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ 2.4G Mouse                                id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad                  id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ TOSHIBA Web Camera - HD: TOSHIB           id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Toshiba input device                      id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Comment: Please see if this helps, [https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/12278/my-touchpad-isnt-working](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/12278/my-touchpad-isnt-working)